# Dictionary KeyError when extending

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to extend the dictionary when a user completes the quiz. I'm looking to store the last three scores only for a user but I get an `KeyError` when I try to add it to the empty dictionary and a unhashable list error when I try to implement the score as a list.

```
studentScores = {}

def quiz():
    print("WELCOME TO THE MATH QUIZ\n")
    global student
    student = input("What is your name? ")
    global classname
    classname = input("Which class are you in? (1, 2, 3) ")
    global score
    score = 0

def addDict():
    global student
    global classname
    global score
    score = str(score)
    studentScores[student + classname, score]
    print(studentScores)
```

Comment: Is this your whole code? When I run it, nothing happens. In any case, `studentScores[student + classname, score]` looks strange to me. That line won't update the dictionary, if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: Did you mean `studentScores[student + classname] = score` ?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict - you clearly didn't even read about syntax on adding / accessing dict elements.

Comment: What are you even trying to do with studentScores?

Comment: Also why are you storing scores as `strings`? Surely you will only have to turn them back to `integers` to compare them later on.

Comment: General remark: don't use all globals: use function arguments and return values properly.

Comment: @Kevin I only posted the parts that were related to my problem.

Comment: @AlexJenkinson, a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is always related to the problem.

Comment: @Nsh This is my first coding language so most of the docs that come with python confuse me as to what they are saying.

Comment: @Evert I've researched function arguments and when I try to implement them into the quiz function it returns with an error.

Comment: Ah, ok; well, that'll be for another question then. But in general, it's better to use them, and get rid of those globals.

Comment: Btw, have you tried going through [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions) or [dive into Python](http://www.diveintopython3.net/)? There still be some programming jargon, but typing in the examples and experimenting with them is the best way to learn.

Comment: @Evert I was using code academy to learn the fundamentals and then using documentation if I didn't understand them. Thank you for the advice about function arguments I figured out what I was doing wrong and not adding them into the addDict() aswell as the function itself. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Yes, the API documentation can be a little daunting for beginners, since it can go into quite some detail and use jargon (like "API"). Good luck with your furhter learnings in Python.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in comments, the problem is on this line:

```
studentScores[student + classname, score]
```

What this line does: It creates a *tuple* of `(student + classname, score)` and uses that tuple as a key to the dictionary. And since that key does not exist, it raises an exception.

```
>>> student = "foo"
>>> classname = "bar"
>>> score = 0
>>> studentScores = {}
>>> studentScores[student + classname, score]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: ('foobar', 0)
```

Instead, you want to use just `student + classname` as the key and *assign* to it the value of `score`.

```
>>> studentScores[student + classname] = score
>>> studentScores
>>> {'foobar': 0}
```

Comment: Thank you this helped me understand more about my problem and dictionaries itself.

Comment: @AlexJenkinson if this helped and solved the problem, you may want to accept the answer, to indicate the problem has been solved.